# Firebase realtime database weird behavior

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

before this morning everything works perfectly with Firebase Realtime database. With my app, I retrieve nodes, update nodes through Firebase components. Since this moring, when I want to see Firebase realtime database on the console, it's blank, nothing to show like this. I already tried to refresh the page, to change for another brower, to log in/log out, it's always the same result : [image]

The most weird is that for some users everything is fine but for others, they can't reach to authenticate on Firebase. They can't read new posts...
So, **what's going on ?**

There are no changes on the app code since 3 weeks and everyting was fine. The only thing is that a couple of days I received a message from Google Cloud Platform saying :

> We’re contacting you because the Node.js project has informed Google that all current versions of v4.x to v8.x are vulnerable to an issue that can be used by an external attacker to cause a denial of service. This includes the current Google Cloud Functions (GCF) runtime Node.js 6.9.1. To mitigate this issue, Google will upgrade all functions to Node.js 6.11.1 on July 20th, 2017. We recommend you test your Cloud Functions with the new runtime version (Node.js 6.11.1) on July 17th.

Maybe that's the issue ? The update not finished well ? (Because I use Cloud functions for some data updates on the realtime database).

Comment: Are you trying to access the firebase console from a browser? Have you tried checking what chrome console says?

Comment: Nope. I tried and I have this message : failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT and then WebSocket is closed before the connection is established.

Comment: Ok. But I don't think anybody can help you if you don't provide some meaningful code

Comment: Ok. I don't provide any code because I don't think it's coming from there. The app/cloud functions code has been working for months. Last update was 3 weeks ago and works perfectly.

Comment: From a deleted answer from @Arrabidas92: "Don't worry, it's only a network issue." I voted to close because of that.